# deleteing hive flutter record using provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-hive

Im new to flutter and im trying to create todo app using flutter, hive and provider.

when i'm trying to delete record using deleteAt method keep getting following exception.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 3
E/flutter ( 4513): #0      RangeError.checkValidIndex (dart:core/errors.dart:303:7)
E/flutter ( 4513): #1      IndexableSkipList._getNodeAt (package:hive/src/util/indexable_skip_list.dart:196:16)
E/flutter ( 4513): #2      IndexableSkipList.getAt (package:hive/src/util/indexable_skip_list.dart:188:26)
E/flutter ( 4513): #3      Keystore.getAt (package:hive/src/box/keystore.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 4513): #4      BoxBaseImpl.deleteAt (package:hive/src/box/box_base_impl.dart:133:28)
E/flutter ( 4513): #5      TaskData.deleteTask (package:flutter_hive_toto/models/task_data.dart:38:14)
E/flutter ( 4513): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4513):
```

by using following code i tried to delete record without any success.

```
  void deleteTask(int index)  async {
    var _taskBox =  await Hive.openBox<Task>('taskbox');
    print(index);
    _taskBox.deleteAt(index);
    getTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've opened `taskbox` and saved a reference to the opened box in `_taskBox`. After opening a box data you should retrieve the saved data in `_taskBox` and then you can access them in order to delete an item in a specific index. Try to save a reference to the box in a different variable and then save retrieved data in `_taskBox`. Please read the [Hive document](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write) for more information on how to read data from a hive box.